# Redirect ALL routes from domain "example.net/*" to "exemple.com/*" using AWS (Route 53, S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect

I'm trying to redirect **any** query from "example.net" to "example.com" using AWS.

I followed this tutorial
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/
and succeeded to redirect the route "example.net" to "example.com".

However, "example.net/test" doesn't redirect to "example.com/test". Only the root route is affected.
I wish to redirect all queries. (example.net/* to example.com/*).

I've been searching for the answer for hours, without success.
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Are you also using CloudFront, or would you be willing to introduce it to your tech stack?

Comment: You can't do this with S3 alone. In addition to the issue you are encountering you will also run into a problem with SSL/HTTPS support. You need to use something like CloudFront or Cloudflare instead or in addition to S3.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i'll try with Cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers i've been provided, I figured it out using CloudFront on AWS

You have to create a CloudFront function : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-redirect-url.html

Then associate it to a CloudFront distribution that you will link to your domain example.net